# What is the even prompted after a UITableView loaded data?

Tags: iphone

As title

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the event?

In the simplest Table Views the data is loaded whether it be from an array or other object in the controllers `viewDidLoad` method.

Then `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`
is implemented which just returns the count of the data source object so the table view knows how many objects it will draw.

And finally `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is implemented to describe how the cells in the table look by returning a table view cell.